# Retrieving the webpage's URL (http) from page source content - Finding out WHICH website was scraped

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, I have been given a sample of >6000 scraped HTML content (page source in txt format). Is there a way I can find out what website was scraped for a particular txt file I have been given?

Say, an agency gave me the HTML (the content you get after 'inspect element') for [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com). But didn't tell me where it was scraped from. So the input would be the HTML file for me and the output 'www.facebook.com'. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So, basically as example you have facebook html code and from that you need to find URL link of that page?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I mean I wouldn't know going in that it is the page source of facebook. I'll have to find it through the scraped content.

Comment: Well what about finding the title tag..? that might be a start atleast..?

Comment: Like the page of this question has the title `python - Retrieving the webpage&#39;s URL (http) from page source content - Finding out WHICH website was scraped - Stack Overflow`. Usually these title tags have the website name so I guess you can find out using `soup.find('title')`

Comment: @Ananth What I have is news article content. This means that there might be so many candidates with the same kind of 'title'. My code interacts with the webpage. Let's say that I did find the webpage from the scraped title. I can use selenium to load the webpage. How will I find the URL after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to get the url of the page that you have. This will depend on what you have in the source code. First let me tell you the easiest way.

I am taking [this link](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2286166-pianists-fitted-with-robotic-thumb-can-learn-to-play-with-11-digits/) as the sample to demonstrate both ways.

Webpages link the relation of the webpage to an external document in the `link` tag. They also give the preferred url of webpage by giving `rel` attribute the value `canonical`.

In simple terms if you can find the `link` tag which has an attribute `rel` with a value `canonical` then that tag will have a `href` who's value is the preferred url of the webpage.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get('https://www.newscientist.com/article/2286166-pianists-fitted-with-robotic-thumb-can-learn-to-play-with-11-digits/')

# You can skip the above step and replace request.text(next line) with the source you have
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')

link = soup.find('link', {'rel': 'canonical'})

print(link['href'])
```

This would give me the output:

```
https://www.newscientist.com/article/2286166-pianists-fitted-with-robotic-thumb-can-learn-to-play-with-11-digits/
```

Now the time consuming one (because uses **Selenium**), if there is no `link` element with  a canonical value in the html code then you have to switch to this.

This is time consuming because we are going to ask google for help. The titles are majorly unique. So if you generally search the title of a webpage the first result is mostly the desired webpage. We have to use `Selenium` for this. `Scrapy` can also be used but I'm using `Selenium` for now.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


# adding options
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# option.add_argument('--headless')
option.add_argument("--log-level=3")
option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

# initialize browser
CDM = ChromeDriverManager(log_level='0')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CDM.install(), options=option)

driver.get('https://google.com')
time.sleep(1)

# Get the title using BS beforehand
title = 'Pianists fitted with robotic thumb can learn to play with 11 digits | New Scientist'

# EDIT 1 Updated the arguments of send_keys method
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(title  + Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)

# EDIT 1 remove the next two lines
# driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]').click()
# time.sleep(1)

result = driver.find_element_by_class_name('yuRUbf')

link = result.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
print(link)

driver.quit()
```

The output was still the same:

```
https://www.newscientist.com/article/2286166-pianists-fitted-with-robotic-thumb-can-learn-to-play-with-11-digits/
```

Since you have like 6000+ webpages to run through, I am assuming that all these are from different websites. If they are from the same website then it's easy to find out if first or second method is needed. Assuming they are a mixture of websites I would suggest mixture of both methods.

If the first method fails while running just create a `dictionary` with `title-html code` as **key-value pair**. After finishing all the pages through `BS` now start using `Selenium` by running through the dictionary. This is better compared to switching between `Selenium` and `BS` in the middle of the loop randomly.

I am suggesting a **dictionary instead of a list** with just the title because if you want to **compare** the source codes later(to check if this is the correct one) you can use it efficiently. If you do not plan on comparing then go with the `lists`.

If you are lucky then you need not get to the second type, I hope you are lucky. This is a great question!

**EDIT 1:**
Updated the `Selenium` code block to avoid Google Suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @Ananth for writing such a detailed answer. The BeautifulSoup leads to a bunch of errors even if there is a canonical link present. So I switched to the Selenium one and it works like a charm!

Comment: I just ran a bunch of pages and found that for some, while searching for titles, google does this 'auto-suggest' thing which masks the search button. In those cases, I am getting an ElementClickInterceptedException. Is there a work-around for that?

Comment: Hey, I have just updated the code block, this will avoid the clicking and press `Enter` as we do normally. Thanks for the update!

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question - I see that some of my HTML files have canonical links. But, when I run the BeautifulSoup (BS) code snip, it is creating a NoneType object. The error is `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.
(I am using the BS method as well because running through the loop I found that a lot of files have titles that yield multiple search results which become misleading.)

Comment: Let us continue in the [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235904/room-for-ananth-and-nilima) I've created. I've added you as well if you don't mind.